# Probability and permutations: getting the wrong answer

Tags: probability

I am having a slight problem solving a probability question, currently I am getting the wrong answer but also a negative probability which is impossible (I also tried switching the term, but still getting the wrong answer). Could someone please identify my error and explain what am I doing wrong. Thanks

The question along with my solution is below:
[image: solution]

Comment: So the question is asking you to permute the letters of the word mathematical and the calculate the probability that the first 5 letters are vowels?

Comment: Yes, that's the question, and also here order doesn't matter

Comment: If "order doesn't matter" then what does it mean to speak of "the first five letters"?

Comment: There is a $\frac 5{12}$ chance that the first chosen is a vowel.  Then a $\frac 4{11}$ chance that the second is also a vowel, and so on...so $\frac {5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{12\times 11\times 10\times 9\times 8}$.

Comment: Order doesn't matter meaning it doesn't matter in which order the letters are placed as long as the first five letters are vowels arranged in any order, and the rest 7 letters are the constants arranged in any order. also the amount of repetitions has to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

What are you even trying to calculate?

Don't make things more complicated then they need to be.   You have 5 vowels and 7 consonants being arranged.   The individual letters don't matter for this question, just the placement of those categories.

> Rearranging the word $\rm CVCCVCVCVCVC$ , what is the probability that the first five positions in the word are all $\rm V$?

There are *how many* equally probable ways to select positions for the vowels and consonants, and of them just $1$ way will place the vowels at the front of the word.   So...

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the question, you need to take into account the repetitions and the number of arrangements possible

Comment: No, @amine , you actually don't; ways to arrange letters within the groups cancels in the division.  There are $4!/(2!2!)$ equally probable arrangements of $\rm cvvc$ of which $1$ has the vowels in the first two places, so the probability is $1/6$.  It doesn't matter if we are actually talking about $\rm MEET$ or $\rm MEAT$.  $$\frac{1}{4!/(2!2!)}=\frac{2!}{4!/2!} = \frac{2!~2!}{4!}=\frac 1 6$$